# Scalable way to add third-level domains

Tags: fortrabbit

Users of my app has an ability be get a third-level domain for them : `my-domain.example.com`. What is the scalable way to manage that on Fortrabbit?

I use CloudFlare for DNS management. I assume I can delegate domains via API with them. How can I automate it on a Fortrabbit side for that domain to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On fortrabbit, you probably don't have to use an API or something.

Just create a domain entry `*.example.com` that points to your document root. You will have to get the subdomain in your code.